# Can I stop data compressing while saving a report in pdf file?

Tags: pdf, ms-word, labview

I am developing a project in LabVIEW 2012 using report generation vis. My reports have some tabular information and few images. I tried generating reports using Report generation Vis of LabVIEW in word as well as html formats. Tables and images look good in both these formats; but since both these formats are editable, I want reports to be saved in pdf file. But while saving reports in pdf format, data compression happens and therefore sharpness of image deteriorates considerably. Is there any option to stop compressing data when report is getting converted to PDF format?

[image]

Comment: Can you show your code ?

Answer (score 1):

The MSDN help for this method is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412305%28v=office.12%29.aspx). I think that adding the [wdExportOptimizedFor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb243313%28v=office.12%29.aspx) with a value of Print should help you. Alternatively you could use Word files with a password.